# Extract the DateTime format from a given date string

Tags: c#

I was wondering if there was a way to extract the DateTime format from a given date string. In C#
For example:

```
var dateString = "12/10/2018";
var format = GetDateFormat(dateString);
```

and then the format will be like 'long date time' or something.

Comment: There is none, at least not built-in. Why? Because `12/10/2018` can be `dd/MM/yyyy` and `MM/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

Via hard-coding or reflection (shown below) you could retrieve the value of all [properties of the `DateTimeFormatInfo` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo#properties-) whose name end with `"Pattern"`, then attempt parsing using those patterns and see which ones are successful.  You're then limited to the patterns provided by that class and whichever culture(s) you choose to use, though.

```
DateTimeFormatInfo formatInfo = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> patternProperties = formatInfo.GetType().GetProperties()
    .Where(property => property.Name.EndsWith("Pattern"));

foreach (PropertyInfo patternProperty in patternProperties)
{
    string pattern = (string) patternProperty.GetValue(formatInfo);
    bool wasParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, pattern, formatInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime _);

    Console.WriteLine($"{patternProperty.Name} (\"{pattern}\"): {wasParsed}");
}
```

On my system (en-US) the above code produces the following output:

```
FullDateTimePattern ("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy h:mm:ss tt"): False
LongDatePattern ("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"): False
LongTimePattern ("h:mm:ss tt"): False
MonthDayPattern ("MMMM d"): False
RFC1123Pattern ("ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH':'mm':'ss 'GMT'"): False
ShortDatePattern ("M/d/yyyy"): True
ShortTimePattern ("h:mm tt"): False
SortableDateTimePattern ("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"): False
UniversalSortableDateTimePattern ("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'"): False
YearMonthPattern ("MMMM yyyy"): False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `DateTime.TryParseExact` with a set of predefined formats. Those that match will be the format(s) you are looking for.

Comment: This wouldn't work, since there are ambiguous possibilities

Comment: The ambiguity is part of the question, not the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in function or anything, but you could write one yourself. Here is a short example that checks for three possible formats; you can add as many more as you like just by adding to the list.

If you need to support unusual formats (e.g. formats that can't be auto-detected by `DateTime.Parse()` then you may need a slightly different solution that tests the input using `DateTime.ParseExact()`, like BACON's answer.

```
public class Program
{
    //Returns a string indicating the format of the input, or null if could not be detected
    public static string GetDateTimeFormatCode(string dateTimeString)
    {
        //Parse the input
        DateTime dateTime;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out dateTime)) return null;

        return
        (
            new string[]
            {
                "M/d/yyyy",
                "d MMM yyyy",
                "d MMMM yyyy",
                "dddd MMMM d yyyy"
            }
        )
        .Where( c => dateTime.ToString(c) == dateTimeString )
        .FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var tests = new List<string>
        {
            @"21 May 2018",
            @"6/21/2018",
            @"Monday May 21 2018"
        };

        foreach (var t in tests)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input '{0}' uses format '{1}'", t, GetDateTimeFormatCode(t) ?? "?");
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Input '21 May 2018' uses format 'd MMM yyyy'
Input '6/21/2018' uses format 'M/d/yyyy'
Input 'Monday May 21 2018' uses format 'dddd MMMM d yyyy'
```

[Code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bxNrzn)